# IDbTransaction and IDisposable

Tags: ado.net, transactions

MSDN do not define what `Dispose`should do for transactions. So my guess is that ADO.NET drivers do not do anything special in it (other than cleaning up resources)?

It would be lovely if it called `Rollback` if neither of `Commit` and `Rollback` has not been called before `Dispose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior (although this may not be officially documented) is to Rollback() if a successful call to Commit() has not occurred prior to the Dispose() being called. This can be verified by disassembling the .NET System.Data assemblies.

Comment: I just checked the npgsql source code. It does the same for it's transaction implementation.